How to Improve Performance When Appending Streaming Data to a DIV Container in Blazor?
We are building a chat application in Blazor that streams responses for frequently asked questions. The streaming data is appended to a <div> container in real time using JavaScript interop with the following approach:
await jsruntime.InvokeVoidAsync("AppendStreamingContainer", data);

As the number of questions and responses increases, we observe the following issues:

The application becomes slower, especially when updating the DOM for the streaming container repeatedly.
Memory consumption grows over time, which worsens the slowness as the container content increases.

Context:

The application relies on a streaming API that provides real-time responses.
Questions are asked frequently, and responses are continuously appended to the same container.
The growing DOM size and memory usage appear to be the main bottlenecks.

Questions:

How can we improve performance and minimize memory consumption while appending frequent streaming data in a chat application?
Are there alternative methods or best practices in Blazor for efficiently handling large numbers of real-time updates?


I would first try virtualizing the container. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-9.0
